# Sql Alchemy Insert Statement failing to insert, but no error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pg8000

I am attempting to execute a raw sql insert statement in Sqlalchemy, SQL Alchemy throws no errors when the constructed insert statement is executed but the lines do not appear in the database.

As far as I can tell, it isn't a syntax error (see no 2), it isn't an engine error as the ORM can execute an equivalent write properly (see no 1), it's finding the table it's supposed to write too (see no 3). I think it's a problem with a transaction not being commited and have attempted to address this (see no 4) but this hasn't solved the issue. Is it possible to create a nested transaction and what would start the 'first' so to speak?

Thankyou for any answers.

Some background:

1. I know that the ORM facilitates this and have used this feature and it works, but is too slow for our application. We decided to try using raw sql for this particular write function due to how often it's called and the ORM for everything else. An equivalent method using the ORM works perfectly, and the same engine is used for both, so it can't be an engine problem right?
2. I've issued an example of the SQL that the method using raw sql constructs to the database directly and that reads in fine, so I don't think it's a syntax error.
3. it's communicating with the database properly and can find the table as any syntax errors with table and column names throw a programmatic error so it's not just throwing stuff into the 'void' so to speak.
4. My first thought after reading around was that it was transaction error and that a transaction was being created and not closed, and so constructed the execute statement as such to ensure a transaction was properly created and commited.

   ```
        with self.Engine.connect() as connection:
            connection.execute(Insert_Statement)
            connection.commit
   ```
5. The so called 'Insert Statement' has been converted to text using the sqlalchemy 'text' function, I don't quite understand why it won't execute if I pass the constructed string directly to the execute statement but mention it in case it's relevant.

Other things that may be relevant:
Python3 is running on an individual ec2 instance the postgres database on another. The table in particular is a timescaledb hypertable taking realtime data, hence the need for very fast writes, but probably not relevant.

Currently using pg8000 as dialect for no particular reason other than psycopg2 was throwing errors when trying the execute an equivalent method using the ORM.

Comment: Add `echo=True` to your `create_engine()` call so you can see if a ROLLBACK really is happening. If so, try using `with engine.begin() as conn:`

Comment: Are you actually calling the commit method?  `connection.commit()` <- note the parentheses.

Comment: That's worked! Thanks so much! I assume that as it was calling ROLLBACK it was a transaction issue? For my own understanding, why does engine.begin() fix the issue?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, ah, no I wasn't. Thanks!

Comment: `engine.begin()` automatically commits, `engine.connect()` automatically rolls back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so this question is answered in case anyone else ends up here:

The issue was a failure to call commit as a method, as @snakecharmerb pointed out. Gord Thompson also provided an alternate method using 'begin' which automatically commits rather than connection which is a 'commit as you go' style transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add `connection.commit()` after `connection.execute()` for SQL Server. Otherwise the `Identity` field is incremented in the table but the transaction is rolled back. Figured this out after lots of troubleshooting.